# Ajax requests not working in wifi with default DNS from my provider

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, dns

I'm working on a cordova app and I'm making some `ajax` requests with `javascript`.

I started having problems with these requests only when my phone was using wifi (in 3g/2g everything works fine).
I also noticed that the problem was **not** occurring when I was running my app on my laptop (connected via wifi), and I understood that it was because I use a different DNS Server on my laptop.
Indeed, I tried to reset the DNS Server and let my provider giving me the default one and the app stopped working like on my phone.

I'm also using `Slim PHP` to create my server-side APIs.

Here is an example:

client side:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: "http://myserver.com/API.php",
   dataType: "json",

   success: function(result) {
      // ....
    }
})
.fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // ...
});
```

server side `API.php`:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo '{"result": ' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
```

So how can I programmatically solve that? Any ideas?

Thanks

**edit**:

I also changed DNS server on my phone (using `8.8.8.8`) and now the app is working fine.